# How to enable pwa with vite-plugin-pwa

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, vite

what do I need to prescribe in order to enable pwa?

when i do "Analyze page load", I get information that
[pwa is disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q2hQ.jpg).

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    VitePWA({
      registerType: 'autoUpdate',
      injectRegister: 'auto',
    }),
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you running in dev by any chance?

> If you want to check it in dev, add the devOptions option to the plugin configuration

```js
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa'
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    VitePWA({
      registerType: 'autoUpdate',
      devOptions: {
        enabled: true
      }
    })
  ]
})
```

Comment: I'm deploying my project

Answer (score 1):

Typically the configuration I use in my projects is always more or less this:

```
VitePWA({
  includeAssets: ["favicon.ico", "apple-touch-icon.png", "logo.svg"],
  manifest: {
    name: "Name App",
    short_name: "Short Name",
    description: "Description",
    theme_color: "#ffffff",
    icons: [
      {
        src: "pwa-192x192.png",
        sizes: "192x192",
        type: "image/png",
      },
      {
        src: "pwa-512x512.png",
        sizes: "512x512",
        type: "image/png",
      },
    ],
  },
})
```